# How to change font style of file names in file manager?

Tags: 14.04, fonts, filemanager

[image]

How & Where do I change the font style and size of the file names displayed in my file manager.

I have unity tweak tool installed but I am just confused on what is controlling the font display in above image.

**EDIT:**

I tried playing around with all the options in the below screenshot(Unity Tweak tool) and nothing is working.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Did you have try using `gnome-tweak-tool` Just run it with `Alt+F2` then type `gnome-tweak-tool`.

if `gnome-tweak-tool` is not available in your platform you can type `sudo apt-get install gnome-tweak-tool` in your terminal. Then you're all set